# When to use <ion-nav> vs Angular router?

Tags: angular, user-interface, navigation, ionic4

Ionic Framework 4 has a navigation component called `Nav` (`<ion-nav>`), which is, according to [Ionic docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/components#nav), intended for the users to

> move between different pages in your app

This overlaps in functionality with built-in Angular router.

When is it better to use Ionic `Nav` component compared to built-in Angular router?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, if you want to dynamically load components without having them tightly coupled to the apps routing, you can use ion-nav. This should help keep the routing files clean.

A use case I can think of is a dynamic list of items leading to different child pages. This should be straightforward with ion-nav compared to angular-routing.

It works a bit like modals but while keeping the navigation behavior you expect when going between normal routes.

You can find a good explanation of its use cases in the docs here: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav/

Comment: Is `<ion-nav>` well-suited for multi-level hierarchical layouts? E.g. what if I have a tree-like structure of pages, where a user may drill down to any node in a tree?